# Fragment Transaction return null in RecyclerView Adapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, fragmenttransaction

I want to start a fragment in method OnClick form RecyclerView.Adapter but I have this trouble

```
07-18 23:07:40.318 15794-15794/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                               Process: com.pedrodelbrete.osbolivia.pedrobrete, PID: 15794
                                               java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager()' on a null object reference
                                                   at com.pedrodelbrete.osbolivia.pedrobrete.Utils.AdapterEncuestaList.InicioFragment(AdapterEncuestaList.java:147)
                                                   at com.pedrodelbrete.osbolivia.pedrobrete.Utils.AdapterEncuestaList$1.onItemClick(AdapterEncuestaList.java:81)
                                                   at com.pedrodelbrete.osbolivia.pedrobrete.Utils.AdapterEncuestaList$CustomViewHolder.onClick(AdapterEncuestaList.java:124)
                                                   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5264)
                                                   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21297)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:743)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5621)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:684)
```

07-18 23:07:40.378 15794-15794/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 15794 SIG: 9

my RecyclerView.Adapter Class

```
public class AdapterEncuestaList extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterEncuestaList.CustomViewHolder> {


EncuestasDisponiblesDBDao encuestasDisponiblesDBDao;

List<EncuestasDisponiblesDB> list;
Context context;
String nombreEncuesta;
long idEncuesta;


private ProgressDialog pDialog;
AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> task;

public AdapterEncuestaList(Context context, List<EncuestasDisponiblesDB> list) {
    this.list = list;
    this.context = context;

}

@Override
public AdapterEncuestaList.CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.encuesta_item, null);
    CustomViewHolder viewHolder = new CustomViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(AdapterEncuestaList.CustomViewHolder holder, int position) {
    encuestasDisponiblesDBDao = DaoAPP.getEncuestasDisponiblesDBDao();
    list = encuestasDisponiblesDBDao.loadAll();
    EncuestasDisponiblesDB encuestasDisponibles = list.get(position);


    nombreEncuesta = encuestasDisponibles.getNombre();
    idEncuesta = encuestasDisponibles.getId();

    holder.itemNombre.setText(nombreEncuesta);

    holder.setItemCLickListener(new ItemCLickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View v, int pos) {
            InicioFragment(v, pos);
            Toast.makeText(context, "Clicl en " + pos, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (null != list ? list.size() : 0);
}

class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    protected TextView itemNombre;


    ItemCLickListener itemCLickListener;


    protected RelativeLayout ryUserItem;

    public CustomViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        //itemNombre = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.itemNmobre);
        itemNombre = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtNombreEncuesta);
        view.setOnClickListener(this);


        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(view.getContext());

    }

    public void setItemCLickListener(ItemCLickListener itemCLickListener) {
        this.itemCLickListener = itemCLickListener;
    }

    //OnClick Listener
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        itemCLickListener.onItemClick(view, getAdapterPosition());

    }


}

public void InicioFragment(View v, int pos) {

    List<EncuestasDisponiblesDB> list;
    encuestasDisponiblesDBDao = DaoAPP.getEncuestasDisponiblesDBDao();
    list = encuestasDisponiblesDBDao.loadAll();
    EncuestasDisponiblesDB encuestasDisponibles = list.get(pos);
    long idEncuesta = encuestasDisponibles.getId();
    //Inicio de menu con Fragment Estadisticas
    //setTitle("Estadisticas");
    Bundle arg = new Bundle();
    arg.putLong("idEncuesta", idEncuesta);
    PreguntasFragment fragment = new PreguntasFragment();


    fragment.setArguments(arg);
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragment.getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.FrameLayoutEncuesta, fragment, "fragment_preguntas");
    transaction.commit();


}
```

}

SOLUTION

in my Adapter Constructor

```
public AdapterEncuestaList(Context context, List<EncuestasDisponiblesDB> list,FragmentManager manager) {
    this.list = list;
    this.context = context;
    this.manager = manager;



}
```

my method IniciarFragment()

```
public void InicioFragment(int Pos,Context context){
     List<EncuestasDisponiblesDB> list;
     encuestasDisponiblesDBDao = DaoAPP.getEncuestasDisponiblesDBDao();
     list =encuestasDisponiblesDBDao.loadAll();
     EncuestasDisponiblesDB enc = list.get(Pos);
     long idEncuesta = enc.getId();

     Bundle arg = new Bundle();
     arg.putLong("idEncuesta",idEncuesta);
     PreguntasFragment fragment = new PreguntasFragment();

     fragment.setArguments(arg);
     FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
     transaction.replace(R.id.FrameLayout, fragment, "fragment_edisponibles");
     transaction.commit();

 }
```

my fragment when I call the AdapterClass

```
 rvAdapter = new AdapterEncuestaList(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),encuestasDisponiblesList,this.getFragmentManager());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like below.

```
fragment.setArguments(arg);
FragmentTransaction transaction = ((youractivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.FrameLayoutEncuesta, fragment, "fragment_preguntas");
transaction.commit(); `
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't Understand what Activity I need in ((yourActiviry))

Comment: Its a Activity in which you bind fragments.

Comment: I do this 
 FragmentTransaction transaction = ((MenuActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
and I have this trouble 
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.pedrodelbrete.osbolivia.pedrobrete.DaoAPP cannot be cast to com.pedrodelbrete.osbolivia.pedrobrete.MenuActivity

when I cast DaoApp, don't find method getSupportFragmentManager(), thanks for your help

Comment: Here I set Adapter to myRecycler View
 List<EncuestasDisponiblesDB> encuestasDisponiblesList = encuestasDisponiblesDBDao.loadAll();

        rvAdapter = new AdapterEncuestaList(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),encuestasDisponiblesList);
        rcEncuestas.setAdapter(rvAdapter);

Comment: I mean it is `fragment` or `activity` where you bind `adapter`.

Comment: I use Fragment to bind Adapter

Comment: You have to write Activity which you bind fragments at youractivity name which i mentioned at code.

Comment: When I do that, I have this trouble java.lang.ClassCastException: com.pedrodelbrete.osbolivia.pedrobrete.DaoAPP cannot be cast to com.pedrodelbrete.osbolivia.pedrobrete.MenuActivity

my code 
FragmentTransaction transaction = ((MenuActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

Comment: I solved my problem, just I pass Fragment Manager like parameter in my Constructor Adapter, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Make changes below

```
public class AdapterEncuestaList extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterEncuestaList.CustomViewHolder> {


EncuestasDisponiblesDBDao encuestasDisponiblesDBDao;
MyItemSelectedListener callback;
List<EncuestasDisponiblesDB> list;
Context context;
String nombreEncuesta;
long idEncuesta;


private ProgressDialog pDialog;
AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> task;

public AdapterEncuestaList(Context context, List<EncuestasDisponiblesDB> list) {
    this.list = list;
    this.context = context;

}

@Override
public AdapterEncuestaList.CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.encuesta_item, null);
    CustomViewHolder viewHolder = new CustomViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(AdapterEncuestaList.CustomViewHolder holder, int position) {
    encuestasDisponiblesDBDao = DaoAPP.getEncuestasDisponiblesDBDao();
    list = encuestasDisponiblesDBDao.loadAll();
    EncuestasDisponiblesDB encuestasDisponibles = list.get(position);


    nombreEncuesta = encuestasDisponibles.getNombre();
    idEncuesta = encuestasDisponibles.getId();

    holder.itemNombre.setText(nombreEncuesta);

    holder.setItemCLickListener(new ItemCLickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View v, int pos) {
            //InicioFragment(v, pos);


getCallBack().myItemClick(v,pos);
                Toast.makeText(context, "Clicl en " + pos, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (null != list ? list.size() : 0);
}



 public interface MyItemSelectedListener{
        void onMyItemSelected(View v ,int position);
    }

    public MyItemSelectedListener getCallback() {
        return callback;
    }

    public void setCallback(MyItemSelectedListener callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
    }



class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    protected TextView itemNombre;


    ItemCLickListener itemCLickListener;


    protected RelativeLayout ryUserItem;

    public CustomViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        //itemNombre = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.itemNmobre);
        itemNombre = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtNombreEncuesta);
        view.setOnClickListener(this);


        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(view.getContext());

    }

    public void setItemCLickListener(ItemCLickListener itemCLickListener) {
        this.itemCLickListener = itemCLickListener;
    }

    //OnClick Listener
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        itemCLickListener.onItemClick(view, getAdapterPosition());

    }


}


public class MyFragment extends Fragments{



 public void onActivityCreated(Bundle b){
    AdapterEncuestaList  adapter=new AdapterEncuestaList (contaxt,list) 
adapter.setCallback(new MyItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMyItemSelected(View v, int position) {
                InicioFragment(v,position);
            }
        });
    recycleview.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void InicioFragment(View v, int pos) {
    List<EncuestasDisponiblesDB> list;
    encuestasDisponiblesDBDao = DaoAPP.getEncuestasDisponiblesDBDao();
    list = encuestasDisponiblesDBDao.loadAll();
    EncuestasDisponiblesDB encuestasDisponibles = list.get(pos);
    long idEncuesta = encuestasDisponibles.getId();
    //Inicio de menu con Fragment Estadisticas
    //setTitle("Estadisticas");
    Bundle arg = new Bundle();
    arg.putLong("idEncuesta", idEncuesta);

    FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.FrameLayoutEncuesta, fragment, "fragment_preguntas");
    transaction.commit();


}
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but don't Work :C, I have this exception 
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                        Process: com.pedrodelbrete.osbolivia.pedrobrete, PID: 28161
                                                                                        java.lang.ClassCastException: com.pedrodelbrete.osbolivia.pedrobrete.DaoAPP cannot be cast to com.pedrodelbrete.osbolivia.pedrobrete.MenuActivity